# trouble using NSMUtableArray in UITableView

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I have a  `NSMutableArray * nameCatalog` which contains pair of `names` and `urls(name, url)`.

If I display `nameCatalog` in `viewDidLoad` like this:

```
for (Catalogue *o in nameCatalog){
        NSLog(@"Catalog: %@", o.url);
    }
```

I get the following links, which is good:

Next I wanna put the `NSMutableArray * nameCatalog` as content to a table.And I implement the following:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:[[nameCatalog objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"url"]];
     NSLog(@"the clicked url:%@", url);

}
```

So when I click the first row of the table it will be displayed the first url....the second and so on.

When I click `first row` it gets displayed this

which is correct.

When I click `second row` it displays this:

which is also correct.

When I click the `third row` it displays this:

```
 (null)
```

which is WRONG!

Where I'm going wrong?

Has anything to do with the fact that the third link contains the `french e`?

in the word `coupé`.

IMPORTANT:

Above for simplisity and for make it clear for everyone I assumed that my `NSMutableArray`
contains only 3 urls.

In fact it contains much more, about 20 urls.And everything is going great except the urls that contain `french e`.When I click those rows of the table `NSLog` displays `null`.

And I'm sure that my `NSMutableArray` contains those links.Please tell me how to fix this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your 3rd string contains 'é' character that may be invalid in url - try to add percent escapes for that character using -stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: function in NSString:

```
NSString *escapedString = [[[nameCatalog objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"url"] stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:escapedString];
```

Comment: It sounds like a good solution, but too late - The NSURL is probably already created from a string containing the french. OP should try escaping *before* creating the NSURL from the string.

Comment: @Danra, he has strings for url, NSURL are created in didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method, so it's not late it seems

Comment: @Vladimir Is better but not perfect.It displays the url but instead of coupé I get coup%C3%A9 .So what next?:D

Comment: @george, to display anything to user use strings you already have with proper symbols. When trying to load something using nsurl - use escaped string, that string is not meant to be displayed to user. coup%C3%A9 is the same as coupé, it just uses proper encoding to make it valid url string

Answer (score 0):

```
use this it work fine   
 NSArray *array=[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"link",@"link",@"link",nil];
        for(int i=0;i<[array count];i++){
            NSString *result = (NSString *) CFURLCreateStringByAddingPercentEscapes(kCFAllocatorDefault, (CFStringRef)[array objectAtIndex:i], NULL, CFSTR("?=&+"), kCFStringEncodingUTF8);
            NSURL *url=[NSURL URLWithString:result];
            NSLog(@"the clicked url:%@", url);
            NSLog(@"%@",[array objectAtIndex:i]);
        }
```